# LLM GPU Scalability for multiple inferences

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, implementation

New to LLMs and have a question on scalability. Supposing I take a pre-trained open-source LLM and only wish to perform inference (eg. a simple chatbot on a local machine).

If it takes me 2 GPUs to run it for one prompt, will it take me 4 GPUs to run it for 2 concurrent prompts / users? Couldn't find any resource regarding this online so would also appreciate if I could be directed to any.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @David, welcome to the site. How are you planning to split the LLM computation for a single prompt between 2 GPUs?